# Approximation for the equation of an imperfect circle

Tags: geometry, differential-geometry, circles, quadratic-forms

Given two random points $(x_0,y_0)$ and $(x_1,0)$ and some condition, I have an equation $C[(x-x_0)^2+(y-y_0)^2]=[(x-x_1)^2+y^2]^2$ which is a perfect circle if I ignore the power (2) on the RHS. However, considering the power on the RHS, which makes it an imperfect circle, I aim to apply some approximation so that I can obtain the equation of a circle i.e. $(x-A)^2+(y-B)^2=r^2$

Just for the illustration, I have taken some random points and plotted the above equation in Mathematica, which gives me an imperfect circle as expected [image: Mathematica]

Comment: *Approximate* center and radius *analytically*? Isn't that kind of contradiction?

Comment: I meant to say finding center and radius analytically through some approximation as this is not an equation of a circle.

Comment: OK. The center is $(0,0)$ and the radius is $14$. That's a very bad approximation most of the time, but without a criterion for success, it's about as good as any other. Can you perhaps spend a little time refining your question so that we (and you) both know the goal we're working toward?

Comment: For the reason John Hughes explained, I'd voted to close this question as unclear.

Comment: @RabeArshad if you ignore the power 2 on the RHS you get a line instead, not a circle.

Comment: Thank you for your comments. I have re-written my question to clarify what my problem is. I hope the question is clear now.

Comment: I think the question is pretty clear.  Just not *completely* specified, which, IMHO, is okay.